# Python parent-child design pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, plotly-dash

**I realize the title is terrible, please feel free to change it or suggest changes to it (I am new to design patters)**

I have a Python based Dash web app (not completely relevant) and I want to add some structure to it, however I am not sure what kind of design pattern to use.

The structure I tried was:

```
-- Parent object (initializes all the configuration and instantiates a data object that the rest of the children will need to use)
|
|- Have child objects with methods that return the layout, which I want to be able to call from the parent object
```

However, I realized this is probably not the best approach since it is difficult to call a child method from the parent object.

Here is an example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = VaccinationData() <-- created parent so I can use this data in entire project
        self.app = dash.Dash()
        self.set_layout()

    def set_layout(self):
        self.app.layout = html.Div(self.child_method()) <-- calling child method

class Child(Parent):
    def child_method(self):
        # Does some data processing with self.data
        return html.Div(
            className="right",
            children=[self.top_stats(), self.pred_full_vacc()], <-- calling more child's child methods
        )
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Parent()
    app.app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**I am quite new to thinking about design patters so would appreciate any help!**

Comment: what are you trying to do? the design pattern depends on your use, if you want a dynamic layout you would need a factory pattern for example, if you want cross figure interactivity you need observer pattern etc

Comment: I want to be able to just instantiate the parent class and have the parent class do everything else (by calling child methods), it's hard to explain, I might just keep it without using classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you trying to create a link between the classes for coexistence and the Parent and Child classes are really related to a parent and their children (since there is a Vaccination Data declared).
In that case you could create a parent class (Person) and 2 child classes (Parent and Child).
So, you could organize your code to leave the methods that both child classes need access on the parent class.
Try to link the classes through coding (like instantiating a variable on the **init** method of the Child that requires a Parent instance to be input).

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean I should have a top level class (Person) then the parent and child classes will be the child of person? Does this mean the parent and child are siblings?

Comment: Yes, they would be siblings. Another option would be evaluate if that 2 classes could not be represented by just one. I’m not sure, looking at the piece of code that you posted, but maybe merging them would make your code clearer. If you’re using just Parent to instantiate e the Child have the methods, why not create one single class with all these together?